# Prove rigorously that $\mathbb E[X\mid 1_B]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(B)}\mathbb E[X1_B]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. $X$ a random variable and $B\in \mathcal F$. How can I prove that $$\mathbb E[X|\mathbb 1_B]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(B)}\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_B] $$
using the definition ?

**Attempts**

I know that
$$\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_B]=\int_{\mathbb R}x\mathbb P(X\in dx, Y=1)$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb R}x\frac{\mathbb P(X\in dx|Y=1)}{\mathbb P(Y=1)}\mathbb P(Y=1)=\mathbb P(B)\mathbb E[X\mid \mathbb 1_B].$$

But can I prove it using $$\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_F]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|\mathbb 1_B]\mathbb 1_F]$$
for all $F\in \sigma (\mathbb 1_B)=\{\Omega ,B,B^c,\emptyset\}$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325815/conditional-expectation-in-the-case-of-mathcala-emptyset-omega-a-ac?rq=1

Comment: It's not right. $E[X \mid 1_B]$ takes one value on $B$ and in general another on $B^c$. But your RHS is just a number.

Comment: I would start by noting $E[X| 1_B]$ is defined as $E[X | \sigma(1_B)]$ and $\sigma(1_B) = \{\emptyset, \Omega, B, B^c \}$, then show your candidate (or a modification of it, since Ian pointed out you’re only right for $\omega \in B$) for the conditional expectation satisfies the two properties $E[X | \sigma(1_B)]$ should satisfy. By uniqueness, we will get that your candidate must equal the quantity $E[X | \sigma(1_B)]$.